# Dump a JSON file and then save to lists

Tags: python, json, string, parsing

This is my code:

```
with open('step3_desired_output.txt') as f, open('jout.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in f:
        jline = json.dumps(line)
        #jline2 = jline['Title']+'\t['+jline['"'+'Actor'+'"']+']'+'\n'
        print jline2
```

I am dumping a JSON file into Python and I want to then combine some of the values to form strings.  Later I'll be parsing the file using pydot.

After dumping the json data into a string in python (jline variable), this is the ouptput:

```
"{\"Title\":\"The Shawshank Redemption\",\"Year\":\"1994\",\"Rated\":\"R\",\"Actors\":\"Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler\",\"Plot\":
```

There are multiple lines like this.  I want to ouput the Title and first 4 Actor values from each line to a text file, like so:

```
Title   ["Actor","Actor","Actor","Actor"]
```

Output is TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

***UPDATE***
In the end I went a different direction and did this:

```
file = open('step3_desired_output.txt','rU')
nfile = codecs.open('step4.txt','w','utf-8')
movie_actors = []
for line in file:
  line = line.rstrip()
  movie = json.loads(line)
  l = []
  title = movie['Title']
  actors = movie['Actors']
  tempactorslist = actors.split(',')
  actorslist = []
  for actor in tempactorslist:
    actor = actor.strip()
    actorslist.append(actor)
  l.append(title)
  l.append(actorslist)
  row = l[0] + '\t' + json.dumps(l[1]) + '\n'
  nfile.writelines(row)
```

Comment: Thanks...I think that is correct now, and is how I have it in my code

Comment: `json.dumps` takes a `Python` object (list, string. dict) and produces a JSON string.  `loads` converts a JSON formatted string into Python. `jline` is a JSON string, not Python.  `line['Title']` works on a Python dictionary, not a string.

Comment: Oh ok, do you know how I could extract the data from jline into the format I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `jline = json.dumps(line)` to `jline = json.loads(line)`.

**Edit**:
You will have the following structure:

```
{'Title': 'The Shawshank Redemption',
 'Year': '1994',
 'Rated': 'R',
 'Actors': 'Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler'}
```

Then you could:

```
jline2 = {jline['Title']: jline['Actors'].split(', ')}
```

So jline2 will be the following:

```
{'The Shawshank Redemption': ['Tim Robbins',
                              'Morgan Freeman',
                              'Bob Gunton',
                              'William Sadler'] }
```

And that structure will be easily traversable.

Comment: The problem is that I want to search through the data and pull out the values and keys.  If I use json.loads then I'm not able to search through it and pull out the actors indvidually, the actors just become one long string.

Comment: Thanks,I managed to do this: `jline2 = {jline['Title']+'\t['+jline['"'+'Actor'+'"']+']'+'\n'` which gave me the quotes around the set of actors, but not around each actor.  I ended up doing what I posted in the edit.